# Knitr options: exact number of digits including trailing zeroes

Tags: r, knitr

Good afternoon,

I'm working on a document in knitr, and we need to print all our results correct to four decimal places, including trailing zeroes. However, the options(digits=X) command in knitr doesn't quite work how I'd like it to. As a MWE (using digits = 2, so I don't need to use scipen in it),

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
options(digits=2)
a <- 0.0012345
print(a)
@
\(a = \Sexpr{a}\)
\end{document}
```

Running this in knitr gives me a result of 0.0012 inside the chunk, and 0 outside the chunk using \Sexpr{}. What I would like is an option that gives me 0.00 (2 decimal places, for this MWE) both inside the chunk and outside the chunk using \Sexpr{}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Note the definition of the `digits` option in [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/print.default.html):

> digits
>   a non-null value for digits specifies the minimum number of significant digits to be printed in values. The default, NULL, uses getOption("digits"). (For the interpretation for complex numbers see signif.) Non-integer values will be rounded down, and only values greater than or equal to 1 and no greater than 22 are accepted.

You're seeing significant digits, rather than decimal places. Try using `sprintf` to get the exact format of numeric values that you want to print.