# knitr: Preserving trailing zeros for consistent number of significant digits/figures

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Is it possible to preserve trailing zeros in a number when generating PDF output with `knitr`/`bookdown` (like *1.0e-9* and **not** *1e-9*) to ensure a consistent number of significant digits across all printed numbers?

Minimal example:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
output: pdf_document
---

`r options(scipen=3, digits=2)`

# Introduction

I would like to have the number $`r signif(1.0e-9, 2)`$ to preserve the format 
including the trailing zero to match the length of $`r signif(1.1e-9, 2)`$.

Using  $`r sprintf(signif(1.0e-9, 2), fmt='%#.2g')`$ doesn't seem to be an option either.
```

There is already a related question on [Knitr options: exact number of digits including trailing zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707963/knitr-options-exact-number-of-digits-including-trailing-zeroes) (and a couple of other ones about the same issue when printing tables or figures), but to my surprise, none of them was identical to my problem.

The `formatdown` package might work, but I would favor a simple solution without additional dependencies.

The important part really is *knitr*'s `format_sci_one()` function in `knitr/R/utils.R`:

```
# scientific notation in TeX, HTML and reST
format_sci_one = function(
  x, format = 'latex', times = getOption('knitr.inline.times', '\\times ')
) {

  if (!(class(x)[1] == 'numeric') || is.na(x) || x == 0) return(as.character(x))

  if (is.infinite(x)) {
    return(
      switch(format, latex = {
        sprintf("%s\\infty{}", ifelse(x < 0, "-", ""))
      }, html = {
        sprintf("%s&infin;", ifelse(x < 0, "-", ""))
      }, as.character(x)))
  }

  if (abs(lx <- floor(log10(abs(x)))) < getOption('scipen') + 4L)
    return(round_digits(x)) # no need sci notation

  b = round_digits(x / 10^lx)
  b[b %in% c(1, -1)] = ''

  switch(format, latex = {
    sci_notation('%s%s10^{%s}', b, times, lx)
  },
  html = sci_notation('%s%s10<sup>%s</sup>', b, ' &times; ', lx),
  md   = sci_notation('%s%s10^%s^', b, '&times; ', lx),
  rst  = {
    # if AsIs, use the :math: directive
    if (inherits(x, 'AsIs')) {
      s = sci_notation('%s%s10^{%s}', b, times, lx)
      sprintf(':math:`%s`', s)
    } else {
      # This needs the following line at the top of the file to define |times|
      # .. include <isonum.txt>
      sci_notation('%s%s10 :sup:`%s`', b, ' |times| ', lx)
    }
  }, as.character(x))
}

sci_notation = function(format, base, times, power) {
  sprintf(format, base, ifelse(base == '', '', times), power)
}

# vectorized version of format_sci_one()
format_sci = function(x, ...) {
  if (inherits(x, 'roman')) return(as.character(x))
  vapply(x, format_sci_one, character(1L), ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It requires an external function, but how about this?

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r prep, echo=FALSE}
myexp <- function(x, fmt = "%0.01e") {
  gsub("(.*)e([-+])?0*(.*)", "\\\\(\\\\ensuremath{\\1\\\\times 10^{\\2\\3}}\\\\)", sprintf(fmt, x))
}
```

`r options(scipen=3, digits=2)`

# Introduction

I would like to have the number $`r signif(1.0e-9, 2)`$ to preserve the format 
including the trailing zero to match the length of $`r signif(1.1e-9, 2)`$.

Using  $`r sprintf(signif(1.0e-9, 2), fmt='%#.2g')`$ doesn't seem to be an option either.

How about this? `r myexp(1e-9)`
````

[image]

(This doesn't check yet for non-scientific notation numbers or similar, but if `sprintf` does not produce the perfect string, then `gsub` simply passes it through unchanged.)

Comment: It does **not** in case you output with *knitr*, because the `sprintf()` function returns a string, which is interpreted as verbatim text by *knitr*. In PDF output, your solution would render as "1.0e-09" and not yield "1.0 \times 10^{-9}" via the *LaTeX* intermediate.

Comment: that's a fair point, ok

Comment: Thanks, this works. The escapes make it a bit difficult to read and I'm not sure how it works for other output formats, but I yields the desired result.

Comment: I'm not a fan of all of the escapes either ... you can use R's newish "raw-strings", ala `gsub("(.*)e([-+])?0*(.*)", r"|\\(\\ensuremath{\1\\times 10^{\2\3}}\\)|", sprintf(fmt, x))`, for a slight improvement in the backslash confusion.